# Chrome extension to create custom alert or watch on any specific section of a site

Tags: chrome

Is there any Chrome extension to create custom alert or watch on any specific section of a site. For example: I want to watch currency conversion rate on a particular site. I know that the position of section where rate is shown is same every time. So if there is some extension which can help me to create a watch on that

And also let me create any number of watch or alert when value changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found some which may help;

- [Page Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd)
- [Distill Web Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/distill-web-monitor/inlikjemeeknofckkjolnjbpehgadgge) : Monitor webpage or feed for changes. Get SMS and email alerts on change detection.

Comment: Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality and add details, thanks!

Comment: I found Page monitor good in starting. But after an upgrade in this I din't find it that useful. Hence I din't provide much detail about that. But I wanted to inform other readers about it so posted it as short answer. I believe you want me to add more detail in the answer or may be no answer like this at all?